# typing a returned function in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a function which returns a function.

```
def fnA( x: int, y: int) -> function:
  def fnB(z: int) -> int:
    return x + y
  return fnB
```

This would allow me to do something like:  `fnA(3,4)(5)` and it would return `12`

BUT because of me not typing the function, I dont know what the definition input is and return type of fnB is.  I was not sure if: `function[int, int]` is the way to do it where the last value is the return type or something?

How do I accomplish this?  When looking at the Typing module i didnt really see anything.

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt yeah, I think that works. I didnt look into Callable as i was hoping it was similarly named `Function` for example! Thank you.